# java log monitor for production applications

Tags: java, logging

What is the best way to show the logs java spring application for debugging the production issues.
I can use the unix logs to debug the issues, but is there any other better ways( or applications ) to view the logs by using any third party logging applications like splunk etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many options. Usually spring boot applications are configured with Java logging framework (logback, log4j etc.) They're pretty flexible and can by themselves send the logging messages to file, console, etc.
Again, usually they send to file.

Here is one option (completely free) that you can do:

Add an "agent" application like logstash/filebeat to read this file and send the data to ElasticSearch. Then you can use a cool viewer called "kibana" to consume the logs.

Whats interesting in this feature is that even if you have many different servers you can get all logs in one place. Google about ELK stack to get more information.

There are even cloud solutions for this approach, called [logz.io](https://logz.io/)

Splunk, greylog and others are other alternatives.